# Facebook Graph API - IG User Insights - Get audience_* metrics

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get `audience_city`, `audience_country`, `audience_gender_age`, `audience_locale` metrics from FB graph API IG user insights endpoint: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/insights

The request I am making:

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://graph.facebook.com/v10.0/17841411377776842/insights?access_token=...&metric=audience_city&period=lifetime&since=1614639600&until=1614812400'
```

and the error returned:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#100) (audience_city) metric supports querying data only till yesterday",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 100,
        "fbtrace_id": "APrDtw-8BzaJSbu4F9Q-RA5"
    }
}
```

The `since` and `until` timestamps are set to accordingly `2`, `4` `March 2021` - so definitely I am not querying "too fresh" data.

The same request for another metric like `online_followers` is working like a charm.

Has anyone met a similar issue and been able to overpass it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you have figured it out by now, but in case someone lands in here, let's help them:

Quoting the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/insights#metrics-and-periods

> Metrics that support lifetime periods will have results returned in an array of 24 hour periods, with periods ending on UTC−07:00. **audience_* metrics do not support since and until range parameters**

So basically when using metrics with the prefix *audience_* you do not need to specify the since/until parameters. The error message is a bit disorienting.

**Update:**
The API documentation has been updated since the question was posted and includes the **audience_*** specification. I did not check that, my bad.
Thank you @Jan for the update and letting me know!

Comment: Hi Dimitris, we have skipped those metrics for our solution. But thank you for giving it a go after such a long time. Checking FB docs through Archive.org - they must have added this info about audience metrics recently as it wasn't there 9 months ago. Thanks!